# Using After The Deadline spellchecker seems to return empty list

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to use the `AfterTheDeadline` API to read some output of my program. This is my tester code:

```
ATD.setDefaultKey('qg2324242424')
errors = list(ATD.checkDocument("Looking too the wter. Fixing your writing typoss."))
print(errors)
for error in errors:
    print("%s error for: %s **%s**" % (error.type, error.precontext, error.string))
    print("some suggestions: %s" % (", ".join(error.suggestions),))
```

I put `list()` before `ATD.checkDocument` because otherwise it just returns a generator object. errors is just an empty list, so the for loop returns nothing. I am using [Miguel Ventura's python 3+ version](https://bitbucket.org/miguelventura/after_the_deadline/overview) to run my code. Any help on how to get the expected output would be appreciated.

Comment: you can iterate through a generator with the same syntax as that of a list. on the outside you won't notice any groundbreaking changes.